# My mousedown event is hijacking my datepicker's onSelect event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a web page with an inline datepicker with some code associated with the onSelect event.  Everything was working great until today, when I added this code:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    alert("test");
});
```

Now the onSelect code doesn't fire.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Binding action to `document` seems to be bad idea, is that really necessary?

Comment: Granted, but would binding the action to another entity that happens to contain the datepicker be any better?

Comment: Does the code fail with nothing in the handler? Or does it specifically have to be an `alert()`?

Comment: With nothing it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/xEhPM/5/ still, handler shouldn't be binded to `document`. Can you provide some extra code or say what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ogur is correct, with nothing it works fine.  I put the alert in to make it simple.  What I'm trying to accomplish...  I have a div with a number of controls and an inline datepicker.  When someone clicks outside the div, I want the control to hide.  My solution involved using the mousedown event and it worked perfectly.  It just broke my datepicker :(

Comment: I see... How about hiding that control when datepicker `onClose` event fires?

Comment: I don't think the onClose event will fire in an inline datepicker.